# How do I personalise a dot plot so I have 2 legends for multiple points and multiple intercepts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Like many others here I am new to R so am slowly learning but for the past 2 weeks (or more!) I have been stuck on one graph trying to personalise it. I'm going round in circles, so maybe someone can give me a hand here?
I am trying to show multiple points for 5 variables on a dot plot. Each of those variables has a cut-off intercept.
SO far I managed to write the code to make the plot, have different symbols for each variable, 5 intercepts of different design and one legend for the 5 variables.
What I am going round in circles on is adding parts to the code to do the following;

- Add a second legend, with a title ("Preference cut-off point) for the
  intercepts, which shows the intercepts symbols (i.e. dotdash, dashed,
  twodash etc).
- Make the points on the plot smaller (I have tried cex
  but everything I do makes them huge, I tried 0.1 but the points get
  larger not smaller as I thought).
- I want to alter my x axis, as there
  is an outlier (an important one) so there is a break allowing the
  other points to become more spread out and readable.
- Reorder my legends so they the same and in a particular order (BS1, BS2, BS3, BS4, BS5) -
  currently muddled up! Reorder my y axis so the species are in
  alphabetical order top to bottom (currently bottom to top)

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated!

This is my code so far; (I tried to add a title for the second legend but it doesnt show up, so obviously that is wrong. ALso the key for the intercepts legend is not right because it shows a graduated line which is not the same as the intercepts on the graph!):

```
BodySize <- Orang1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(`BS1`)) %>%
  sample_n(29) %>%
  gather(key = "Class", value = "Mean", "BS2", "BS1", "BS3", "BS4", "BS5")

ggplot(BodySize, aes(Mean, `ï..Latin`, fct_reorder2(`ï..Latin`, Class=="BS3", Mean, .desc = TRUE), 
black=Class, shape = Class)) +
  geom_point() +  ggtitle("Preferences according to BS") + ylab("Tree Species") + xlab("Manly's Alpha 
(a)") +
  theme_dotplot + geom_vline(xintercept=0.06666667, linetype="dotted", color = "black", size=0.25) + 
geom_vline(xintercept=0.05, linetype="twodash", color = "black", size=0.25)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0.05263158, linetype="longdash", color = "black", size=0.25) + 
 geom_vline(xintercept=0.04545455, linetype="dotdash", color = "black", size=0.25) + 
geom_vline(xintercept=0.07142857, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=0.25) + 
 theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "italic")) +

geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.07142857, linetype = "BS5 Alpha threshold"), show.legend = NA) + 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.06666667, linetype = "BS1 Alpha threshold")) + 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.05000000, linetype = "BS2 Alpha threshold")) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.05263158, linetype = "BS3 Alpha threshold")) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.04545455, linetype = "BS4 Alpha threshold")) +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Alpha preference thresholds"))
```

Help greatly appreciated!

#Post edited from here;
Here is my dput(BodySize)

> dput(BodySize)
> structure(list(ï..Latin = c("PL", "SY", "NO", "XY", "CB", "BR",
> "GH", "GL", "BR", "CA", "MA", "ST", "GY", "PA", "TE", "PO", "EL",
> "MT", "GA", "LI", "GR", "AL", "DI", "DH", "HO", "SH", "SA", "LR",
> "FI", "PL", "SY", "NO", "XY", "CB", "BR", "GH", "GL", "BR", "CA",
> "MA", "ST", "GY", "PA", "TE", "PO", "EL", "MT", "GA", "LI", "GR",
> "AL", "DI", "DH", "HO", "SH", "SA", "LR", "FI", "PL", "SY", "NO",
> "XY", "CB", "BR", "GH", "GL", "BR", "CA", "MA", "ST", "GY", "PA",
> "TE", "PO", "EL", "MT", "GA", "LI", "GR", "AL", "DI", "DH", "HO",
> "SH", "SA", "LR", "FI", "PL", "SY", "NO", "XY", "CB", "BR", "GH",
> "GL", "BR", "CA", "MA", "ST", "GY", "PA", "TE", "PO", "EL", "MT",
> "GA", "LI", "GR", "AL", "DI", "DH", "HO", "SH", "SA", "LR", "FI",
> "PL", "SY", "NO", "XY", "CB", "BR", "GH", "GL", "BR", "CA", "MA",
> "ST", "GY", "PA", "TE", "PO", "EL", "MT", "GA", "LI", "GR", "AL",
> "DI", "DH", "HO", "SH", "SA", "LR", "FI"), Species = c("R", "J",
> "Q", "K", "G", "B", "GG", "AA", "DD", "U", "O", "EE", "W", "BB",
> "N", "L", "S", "FF", "M", "P", "X", "B", "CC", "G", "HH", "V",
> "Y", "T", "Z", "R", "J", "Q", "K", "G", "B", "GG", "AA", "DD",
> "U", "O", "EE", "W", "BB", "N", "L", "S", "FF", "M", "P", "X",
> "B", "CC", "G", "HH", "V", "Y", "T", "Z", "R", "J", "Q", "K",
> "G", "B", "GG", "AA", "DD", "U", "O", "EE", "W", "BB", "N", "L",
> "S", "FF", "M", "P", "X", "B", "CC", "G", "HH", "V", "Y", "T",
> "Z", "R", "J", "Q", "K", "G", "B", "GG", "AA", "DD", "U", "O",
> "EE", "W", "BB", "N", "L", "S", "FF", "M", "P", "X", "B", "CC",
> "G", "HH", "V", "Y", "T", "Z", "R", "J", "Q", "K", "G", "B",
> "GG", "AA", "DD", "U", "O", "EE", "W", "BB", "N", "L", "S", "FF",
> "M", "P", "X", "B", "CC", "G", "HH", "V", "Y", "T", "Z"), BS1_pref = c(NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.07142857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, 0.07142857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, 0.07142857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, 0.07142857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> 0.07142857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BS2_pref = c(NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, 0.07692308, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, 0.07692308, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, 0.07692308, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> 0.07692308, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.07692308,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), BS3_pref = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA), BS4_pref = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05263158, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05263158, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05263158, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05263158, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.05263158, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
> ), BS5_pref = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04545455, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04545455, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04545455, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04545455, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.04545455, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
> Class = c("BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1",
> "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1",
> "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1",
> "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS1", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2",
> "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2",
> "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2",
> "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS2", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3",
> "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3",
> "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3",
> "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS3", "BS4",
> "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4",
> "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4",
> "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4", "BS4",
> "BS4", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5",
> "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5",
> "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5", "BS5",
> "BS5", "BS5", "BS5"), Mean = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.065976415, 0,
> 0, 0.003021821, 0.527811318, 0, 0, 0.012566936, 0, 0.01570867,
> 0.005441354, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.047982847, 0.005555909,
> 0.023285793, 0.003852637, 0.005026774, 0.019863867, 0, 0.263905659,
> 0.006984635, 0.003250711, 0, 0, 0, 0.009939673, 0.019879346,
> 0.009370608, 0.051686299, 0.226127559, 0, 0.049225047, 0.024612523,
> 0.038457068, 0.018649696, 0, 0, 0, 0.02199417, 0.004102087,
> 0, 0.070481317, 0.002720332, 0.114013895, 0.018863613, 0.012306262,
> 0.038903666, 0, 0.258431496, 0.015547057, 0.007235737, 0,
> 0.03595257, 0, 0.022124658, 0.044249317, 0.028542498, 0.230096447,
> 0.07190514, 0, 0.054784868, 0, 0.044512706, 0.017790962,
> 0.04793676, 0, 0.115048224, 0.042837105, 0, 0, 0, 0.060551697,
> 0.016918856, 0.058783764, 0.010956974, 0.07422466, 0, 0,
> 0.017220051, 0.004007182, 0.033533783, 0, 0, 0.049010913,
> 0.049010913, 0.025534312, 0.127428375, 0, 0.014817253, 0.121360357,
> 0.030340089, 0.049302645, 0.039410837, 0.053095156, 0, 0.127428375,
> 0.020334315, 0.010113363, 0, 0.057921988, 0.02012027, 0.018739467,
> 0.065109388, 0.018204054, 0.047956915, 0, 0, 0, 0.014579874,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.312065373, 0.024332251, 0.231819992, 0, 0.026955813,
> 0, 0.110390472, 0.006899405, 0.011949484, 0, 0, 0, 0.049323402,
> 0.027597618, 0, 0.105372723, 0.024402104, 0, 0.016921167,
> 0, 0.037390321, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -145L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately we can't really see what is going on here and figure out how to help without some example data. The easiest way to share data is to post the output of `dput(BodySize)` (if it has <100 rows). If the data is sensitive, could you illustrate your problems with an built-in dataset or generated dummy dataset?

Comment: For reordering the legends and y-axis, have you tried using `order()` or `arrange()`? I've gotten around that problem in the past by just reordering the dataset before plotting.

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand I will upload a dummy dataset.

Comment: @4redwood thanks for your reply. No I havent tried that. Where would I insert that piece of code? Would it be after aes?

Comment: @teunbrand I have added dput(BodySIze) now to my post. Does this help show what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2):

So here is how I would go about plotting this. As there are multiple points adressed, I'll comment at the relevant points in the code.

```
library(tidyverse)

# I presume you rather do not have 5 geom_vline() statements.
# Instead, we can use a second dataframe that makes it easier.
Prefs <- BodySize[, paste0("BS", 1:5, "_pref")] %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:5) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(outlier = FALSE)

# We make a new variable that determines if a point is an outlier.
# Later, we'll put the outliers in a different facet.
BodySize$outlier <- BodySize$Mean > 0.4

ggplot(BodySize, aes(Mean, `ï..Latin`, fct_reorder2(`ï..Latin`, Class=="BS3", Mean, .desc = TRUE), 
                     shape = Class)) +
  # To adress your 2nd point, we can simply use the `size` argument to control size
  geom_point(size = 1) +  
  ggtitle("Preferences according to BS") + 
  xlab("Manly's Alpha (a)") +
  # To adress your 1st point, to get the linetypes as a legend, 
  # you need to map a variable to a linetype.
  geom_vline(data = Prefs, aes(xintercept = value, linetype = name)) +
  # Then, we can define a scale for the linetype that controls the legend.
  scale_linetype(name = "Preference cut-off point",
                 labels = paste0("BS", 1:5, " Alpha threshold")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_extended()(range(BodySize$Mean))) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    limits = sort(unique(BodySize$`ï..Latin`), decreasing = TRUE),
    name = "Tree Species"
  ) +
  # To adress your 3rd point, I do not recommend axis breaks, but facets instead.
  # Setting the scale and space to "free_x" preserves distances.
  facet_grid(~ outlier, scale = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Alpha preference thresholds")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "italic"),
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: One thing - on the threshold legend is this the only way to show the different dash/dotdash/twodash etc. lines? It just doesn't seem very clear, particularly between BS3 and BS4.

Comment: If you like to have them differently, you can set the `key_glyph` in the layer. For example, for horizontal lines: `geom_vline(data = Prefs, aes(xintercept = value, linetype = name),             key_glyph = draw_key_path)`.